# Magento, Advance the Catalog Price Rule Conditions by SKU

Tags: magento

I want to define a new Catalog Price Rule Condition, in this Magento Backend window (**Promotions->Catalog Price Rules->Add new Rule->Conditions**), to make some screenshots.

[image: Overview:]

Here the drop down list after I clicked on it:

[image: Missing dro down item]

As you are able to see now, the drop down item "SKU" is missing completly.

I am searching a way to add this listpoint ("SKU") to the drop down list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Knorke, you can do it from magento admin section

go to `Admin->Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes` than click on SKU to edit it and from edit screen

set Use for `Promo Rule Conditions = Yes`

and save the attribute and clear the cache.

if require than re-index the data.